Error in KivyMD: Unknown class <MDToolbar>
I have an error in KivyMD:
Unknown class <MDToolbar>

I have both KivyMD and Kivy libraries installed.
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'Demo Application'
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.navigation_draw()]]
            right_action_items: [["dots-vertical", lambda x: app.callback()], ["clock", lambda x: app.callback_2()]]
            elevation:5
            
        MDLabel:
            text: 'hello world'
            halign: 'center'

The Python code:
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
import kivy


class UltimateApp(MDApp):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    def build(self):
        
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    UltimateApp().run()

I tried to installing the KivyMD library but it sais that it's already installed.
and i searched in stack overflow and i didnt found anything

Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you share your error message and also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
